# Given multiple sets, how do I find the smallest subset of each set that is unique to all other subsets?

Tags: algorithm, set, unique

**Background**. I have numbers 1 to 20 (white digits on black background) that can appear on screen, and I wish to identify these numbers. As they cannot be simply copy-pasted, I will be comparing the position of the white pixels of the number on-screen with a list of positions of white pixels of all 20 numbers. However, each number can have a large number of pixels, and comparing all of those pixels may not be necessary to identify that number. Hence, I'd like to make the least number of comparisons as possible.

**Algorithmic question:** I have multiple sets with elements that are unique within each set, but may not be unique across all sets. How can I find the smallest possible subset of each set such that each subset is unique?

**Example 1:** Let A = {1, 2}, and B = {3, 4}. The smallest subset of A and B would be {1} and {3} (or {2} and {4}), as those subsets are unique to each original set, and are as small as possible.

**Example 2:** Let A = {1, 2, 3, 4}, B = {1, 2, 3, 5}, C = {1, 2, 4, 5}. Possible smallest subsets are {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {4, 5}. If any element were removed from any of those subsets, then that subset can also belong to a different set. E.g. removing 4 from the first subset will leave {3}, which makes it ambiguous if the {3} identifies the first or the second set.

Comment: Can you provide another example with more numbers?

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya I've added another example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a solution with O(n^3) time complexity, and O(n) memory complexity. (If I am not wrong)

```js
function isElement(elem, s) {
  return s.includes(elem)
}

function isId(id, sets) {
  let setsWithSuchElementsNumber = 0
  for (const s of sets) {
    if (id.every((e) => isElement(e, s))) {
      setsWithSuchElementsNumber++
    }
  }

  return setsWithSuchElementsNumber === 1
}

function getSetId(s, sets) {
  const count = {}
  const elements = []
  for (const elem of s) {
    if (count[elem] == null) {
      elements.push(elem)
    }
    count[elem] = 0
  }

  for (const otherSet of sets) {
    for (const e of elements) {
      if (isElement(e, otherSet)) {
        count[e]++
      }
    }
  }

  elements.sort((first, second) => {
    return Math.sign(count[first] - count[second])
  })

  for (let idSize = 1; idSize <= elements.length; idSize++) {
    const possibleId = elements.slice(0, idSize)

    if (isId(possibleId, sets)) {
      return possibleId
    }
  }

  return null
}

const getSetIds = (sets) => {
  return sets.map((s) => getSetId(s, sets))
}

const res = getSetIds([
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [1, 2, 3, 5],
  [1, 2, 4, 5],
])

console.log(res.join(' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote a Python package that is intended to solve your algorithmic question efficiently: https://github.com/alussana/TrieSUS

I stumbled upon an equivalent problem, and I was quite surprised not to find a name for this algorithmic question. I could only find brute-force approaches that involve enumerating and comparing powersets to find the solution(s) for each set - which is very inefficient, and especially slow when considering sets for which a solution doesn't exist.

My algorithm uses a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure and a series of linear time operations to first greatly reduce the problem size, and to then transform it into the equivalent of a [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem), the solution of which is extracted using [OR-Tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization)'s constrained programming solver. More information about the algorithm and its performance can be found in the [repository](https://github.com/alussana/TrieSUS).